# Display one css style if IE and another if ff or chrome in .css using PHP

Tags: php, css

I have some CSS style that does not work in IE and that works on ff and chrome.  I want to be able to use if else.  But can PHP ifelse be included in the .css file for me to achieve?

[edit]

I dont want two .css files for the purpose

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What CSS works in IE but not Chrome/FF?

Comment: Re: your edit ("I dont want two .css files for the purpose"): Why?

Comment: A lot actually - all the proprietary IE filters for instance.

Comment: @cletus These dont work on IE 8
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;


@pinkgothic because I will have 2 css files to manage/edit what ever, saves time and effort

Comment: @Jean: You have to manage the code regardless of whether you split it into two files, though. Same time and effort, excepting the second it takes to load the other file from disk additionally into your editor of choice. Meanwhile, the benefit of having two files is, as alluded to below, less overhead, more reliability, etc.

Comment: @Jean but IE doesn't break with those properties. It just doesn't support them. Why complicate it by having two CSS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to hide a CSS file from other browsers.

If you really want to decide which CSS to serve, server-side, then you could look at parsing the [user agent string](http://www.dotvoid.com/2007/01/parsing-the-user-agent-string-using-php/) to determine which browser is being used; but beware, that can effortlessly be fake - some browsers even let you pick what they'll identify as out of the box, so you might end up with false positives.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking you don't want to customize your site for different browsers. You want to make everything as uniform as possible. Of course there are instances where you have to do things in a browser-specific way but in my experience, with proper techniques, these situations are uncommon.

Some general rules:

1. **Always** declare a [`DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) on *all* your HTML pages. This forces browsers (most notably IE) into so-called standards compliant rather than quirks mode. Quirks mode does things in IE like have an incorrect box model. For this reason I *suspect* you're doing things the wrong (quirky) way and FF/Chrome are actually interpreting it correctly. This is, to me, the most likely scenario; and
2. Use a reset CSS. Different browsers (and different versions of the same browser) have different defaults for padding, margins, borders, etc. It's best to reset it all to the same starting point and go from there.

Beyond that you can use the [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: Very true @ not browser sniffing. I like to link to http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html to explain the true horrors of user agent sniffing and what it's done so far - even if that's heavily JS-centric write-up, the core points remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* interpret CSS files with PHP (if you're not too bothered about server load), if you put this line in your Apache configuration:

```
addhandler application/x-httpd-php .css
```

Then you can try to rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but beware it is not guaranteed to be trustworthy.

However, there are (IMO) better ways to achieve this, which include using IE's conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" ... />
<![endif]-->
```

Of course the most preferable way would be to rewrite your styles to avoid browser implementation differences, which is usually possible, but requires some level of CSS guru-ness if you're being forced to support an old browser like IE 6.

Comment: Agreed, you'll find performance issues if every CSS request has to be run through the PHP interpreter.  Much better to use conditional comments to override the necessary bits of CSS for IE.

Comment: I should be able to select styles without altering the httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

Css does not support conditional flow control. You should resolve on different techniques:

- Have PHP to print out the CSS rules based of some browser sniffing. **I do not raccomend this**
- include different css with the *link* tag into the header section using conditional comments
  (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)