# How to make a html code that uses different CSS styles according to different browsers?

Tags: css, html

I know that using conditional comments will work of IE browsers (Except IE10), but i want to know how to do same in Firefox and chrome. 
Do i need to create different stylesheets for different browsers?
Please answer with a example of some small code, so i can get it well. 
**NOTE:** I m not that good at javascript, so if answer is using javascript, please make some simple script.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>

    <link href="IEStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]-->


</head>
<body>
        <div class="Container">
            <header>
            </header>
            <nav>
            </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <section class="main_articles">
                    <article class="siteDescription">
                        <div class="desImage">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="des">
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </section>

                <aside class="side_article">
                    <div class="ads">
                        This is a Advertisement.
                    </div>

                    <div class="ads">
                        This is a Advertisement.
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227531/different-css-for-each-browser

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to create different stylesheets for different browsers?

In general, no. Why do you think you might need to?

Comment: can u show me an example with just a small code plz .

Comment: An example of what? What is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: i found a solution, showing something like this
@-moz-document url-prefix(){}

Comment: can i know what does this url-prefix() means and why it is sticked with @-moz-document?

Comment: At some point are you going to tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ok never mind, i really didn't know what is this, but u answerd me preety good by giving negative rating to all answers and my question. I found this thing by researching on google and now will be solving my problems from there only now.  I hate this community , So BYE Forever. And Give me highest possible negative rating for this question,and if possible delete my questions and my account from this community,and as u r high reputed u can do it i think. BYE.