# Replacing CSS Selectors that supposingly an X browser does not support

Tags: css, html

So we suppose we want to create and HTML site and we want to use the below CSS Selectors:

***.error* but our browser does not support- class selector (.error)**

***#footer* but our browser does not support- id selector (#footer)**

***a:link* but our browser does not support -pseudo-class :link**

***[lang|="en"]* but our browser does not support- [attr|=value] and also pseudo-class :lang()**

***:not(:first-child)* but our browser does not support pseudo-class :not()**

***img:not(:first-of-type)* but our browser does not support pseudo-class :not()**

***li:nth-child(-n+3)*but our browser does not support pseudo-class :nth-child()**

Does anybody know how we can write the above selectors without the ones that our browser does not support? Only think i have found so far is that we can use **[class~="error"]** instead of **.error**.

Comment: I dont use any browser . The X browser is hypothetical. Probably all the browsers support the above i just want an answer out of curiosity.

Comment: You mentioned 'the above CSS selectors', but I'm not seeing any and the title doesn't mention any as well.
Which browser is giving you this error? And have you tried running it on different browsers?

Comment: @Angelo I guess (s)he just meant "below"

Comment: Some of you examples [are level 1 selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) which are supported by all browsers.

Comment: I said already i know all browsers support most of the above. My question is how to write them/apply them with different syntax if we **SUPPOSE** that an **hypothetical browser** does not support the above selectors on the right side.

Comment: What's the point of that "hypothetical browser" if it doesn't support the simplest selectors?

Comment: What's the context here? What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: I never said i have a problem i have a a question that needs an answer. To put it simply. I want to use a CSS Selector(any css selector doesn't matter) but i want to use it witout a specific pseudo-class or the selector itself( by using html code i guess) is there a way to do that? And if yes what way?

Comment: _"by using html code i guess"_ - you can use the `style` attribute => `<p style="color: red">foobar</p>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the recent browsers support **all** the possible *CSS selectors* including *Attribute selectors*.
Compatibilty list:

- https://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

However, to feed your curiosity, it's possible to link a **stylesheet** to a specific browser. Only, it's not that easy, you'll have to apply it with **Javascript**. I invite you to read the following topic regarding this matter:

- [Different CSS for each browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227531/different-css-for-each-browser)