# Is their any way to implement a css code that should work only on IE?

Tags: html, css

I am design a page in css which should have a specific width in IE and Another width for all other browser. Is theor any way to achive this.
Does @support works on IE

Comment: I think this topic is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227531/different-css-for-each-browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    ////apply your styling
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This conditional statement works, but it is very messay and you have to consider all versions which you have to target.